# Phonegap push notification does not appear in Status bar nor in Lock screen for iOS using the PushPlugin plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

## Intro

I'm using [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) 4.2 (based on Cordova 5.0) to create a cross-platform app.

For iOS I'm using Xcode 6.0 and I'm using the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) Cordova plugin to handle Push Notifications.

## My Problem

I am able to receive push notifications *within* the app in the iOS version, but **when the app is running in the background then I do not receive any push notifications** and they do not appear in the status bar nor in the lock screen. By *background* I mean when the app is closed.

## Details

### Referencing

I include the PushPlugin plugin in the config.xml properly:

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
    <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin" />
</feature>
```

I'm referencing the PushPlugin JavaScript object properly in the index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/PushNotification.js"></script>
```

### Attaching the push-notification event

I have properly attached the notification event to the method onNotificationAPN:

```
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' || device.platform == 'amazon-fireos')
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, 
    {
        "badge":"true",
        "sound":"true",
        "alert":"true",
        "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
    });
}
```

*tokenHandler* and *errorHandler* are defined and so is *onNotificationAPN*;

```
function onNotificationAPN(e)
{
    // handle APNS notifications for iOS
    if (e.alert)
    {
        // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
        // Note that I have org.apache.cordova.dialogs aswell
        navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
        // This code snippet runs fine when the app is open: the app receives the push notification and it's alerted to the user.
    }
    if (e.sound)
    {
        // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
        // Note that I have org.apache.cordova.media plugin aswell
        var snd = new Media(e.sound);
        snd.play();
    }
    if (e.badge)
    {
        pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
        // This code snippet works fine when the app is open: the app receives a push notification and when I close the app the badge count is set to 1, whether that's an expected behavior or not I'm not sure but not what matters right now. 
    }
}
```

As said, the app does receive and alerts notifications pushed to it when the app is open. 
The device does not seem to notice the push, however, when the app is not open. I'd expect the push notification to appear in the lock screen and or in the status bar.

### The testing device

I'm testing on an iPad which's OS version is 7.0.3.

### Provisioning profile

I'm using a development provisioning profile and the device I'm using for testing has been added to the App's devices in the apple development center.

### The push-notification's payload

The payload that's being sent in the Push Notifications looks like this:

```
Msg: {
    "sound":"beeb.wav",
    "alert":"Here is a testing push notification",
    "badge":"1",
    "location":"", // Custom variable
    foreground:"1"
}
```

I've tried changing the foreground variable to 0 and replace foreground with background but it doesn't really change anything.

### Notification Center

I have configurated the notification center for the app as it should be:

- Badge App Icon is ON.
- Sounds is ON.
- Show in Notification Center is ON.
- Include is set to 5 Recent Items.
- Show on Lock Screen is ON.

## Help?

I've been looking around a lot but I'm sort of blank, I'd appreciate if Stack-overflow can help. I usually stick to answering questions but now it's my turn to ask :)

Comment: how are you sending the push notifications? that doesn't seem a valid payload

Comment: @jcesarmobile Using PHP to do it. Got a valid certificate and contacting the sandbox service. The response from the service appears to be positive and note that I am receiving the push notification within the app, so I'm not sure how it's invalid. Could you demonstrate?

Comment: by how are you sending? I wanted you to show the code, not just tell me you use PHP.

Comment: I think is wrong because you don't have the aps key: For each notification, compose a JSON dictionary object (as defined by RFC 4627). This dictionary must contain another dictionary identified by the key aps. The aps dictionary can contain one or more properties that specify the following user notification types (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: @jcesarmobile I'll check into this, thanks, it's still weird that the app accepts the push but not the device itself.

Comment: I think that happens because the app receives the whole payload, so you can pick the data you need, but notification center needs the right payload with the aps key, and the alert to show the message

Comment: @jcesarmobile My object now looks like this: {"asp":{"alert":"Dummy notification","location":"dummy location","badge":1,"sound":"beeb.wav"}} but It's making no difference. This looks legit right?

Comment: @jcesarmobile For the love of all that is holy...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. That means it worked? or you just misspelled your comment and you where really using aps?

Comment: @jcesarmobile Forgive me for the confusion! It was spelled incorrectly in the code, just like you said. I changed it from "asp" to "aps" AND IT WORKS!!! Thank you so much. Please, summarize the pinpoints you've made and make an answer out of it. I'll mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: done, let me know if I missed something

Comment: @jcesarmobile I think that's sufficient, thanks!

Comment: @jcesarmobile If you're familiar with the phonegap environment then I'd appreciate if you could take a look at my new question (third one on SO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119079/phonegap-handling-push-notification-once-ive-left-the-main-scope-with-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push notification payload need an aps key, and an alert with the message that will be displayed:

> For each notification, compose a JSON dictionary object (as defined by
> RFC 4627). This dictionary must contain another dictionary identified
> by the key aps. The aps dictionary can contain one or more properties
> that specify the following user notification types

> - An alert message to display to the user
> - A number to badge the app icon with
> - A sound to play

[More info](https://web.archive.org/web/20160827193216/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

Payload example:

```
  {

    "aps" : {

        "alert" : "You got your emails.",

        "badge" : 9,

        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"

    },

    "acme1" : "bar",

    "acme2" : 42

}
```

When the app is in foreground you receive the whole payload and you can handle it even if it doesn't have that format, but when the app is in backgroud or closed, the system needs the aps key and the alert with the message that will be shown on the notification center.